# Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'C:\core/vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\Users\zu

Tags: php, laravel

I got an error:

> Warning: require_once(C:\core/vendor/autoload.php): failed to open
>   stream: No such file or directory in
>   C:\Users\zumos\Desktop\ecom2\core\public\index.php on line 25
>
> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required
>   'C:\core/vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in
>   C:\Users\zumos\Desktop\ecom2\core\public\index.php on line 25

Comment: Did you come here just to post your errors or do you have a question? Read [ask] and create a [mcve]

Answer (score 4):

In your project folder, the **vendor folder** is missing so you got this error:

> Warning: require_once(C:\core/vendor/autoload.php): failed to open
>   stream: No such file or directory in

The solution is simple, run this two commands:

```
composer update --no-scripts
```

It will Skips execution of scripts defined in `composer.json` file.

```
composer update
```

It will update your dependencies as they are specified in `composer.json` file.

With these two commands, you will re-create the **vendor folder** in your project

Comment: actually i hav to run his project on local server but early this project is on live server and wotking fine on live server now i have only bacjup file from sever and i have  to make change in it on loval server i already make changes  in .env file amd import the sql file change the chdir also

Comment: @zumosun Your folder is in htdocs? Check your error locations: **C:\Users\zumos\Desktop\ecom2\core\public\index.php on line 25**     Place your PHP Project files in the "htdocs" folder located under the "XAMPP" folder on your `C:` drive. The file path is `C:\xampp\htdocs` for your Web server.

Answer (score 0):

Is `vendor` folder exist there in root directory ? If not then try to run `composer install` command.

Comment: `root` directory means in your case in `core` directory, is `vendor` folder exist in `core` directory ?